Why does chocolate spread shortly taste less good once opened?
Chocolate-hazelnut spreads are said to have a relatively long shelf life even after being opened, e.g. 12 months for regular jars on the official FAQ for Nutella.
However, I personally find that once it's been opened, a spread's taste will worsen after just a few weeks, even with the jar closed again. That is on the order of a good-quality spread now feeling like a low-price one.
I believe I've observed this many times, with various spread brands and in various places (other people's homes, etc.).
I am under the impression that it's more specifically the surface of the paste that has degraded flavor and that it has to do with it being in contact with air.
Am I mistaken in thinking that the flavor of an opened chocolate spread quickly degrades, and if not, is it because of the air in the jar?

Can you please elaborate how you store the open jar?

A shelf in my living room, no direct sunlight, temperature may vary e.g. warmer in summer, down to 16-18°C at night in winter. Edit: and of course with the lid on it.

If your winter nights are as high as 16–18°C, then it might help for you to spell out how your hot summer days are!  (Where I am, not every summer day reaches 16°C, and no winter or spring days do…)

I live in France. During winter I have heating which I'll set to somewhere between 19-22°C during the day, and a couple degrees lower at night. During summer, I don't have air conditioning in my living room so temperature may range 20-35°C. My question applies to winter too.

Almost certainly oxidation to some extent, though there are antioxidants in the form of emulsifiers added to nutella. Bit of a complex question though as there are a bunch of things that go into taste perception, such as texture, which could play a role here.

I think it's more like the makers do cheat by keeping the good tasty flavor ingredients limited to the top 20% of the jar.
I have noticed the same with Nutella.
The first dozen of spoons are rich in hazelnuts aroma, but when I get to a certain depth it just turns into a flat tasting choclate over saturated with sugar.

Nutella, like similar spreads, is made in large homogeneous batches and jars are filled from that. Only a single filling nozzle is used. It would not be possible to put the “good tasty flavor ingredients” in a particular part of the jar.

@abdou I have to say I don't believe in your explanation either, but I thank you for making me not alone in having that experience! :)
